# Ramified complete discrete valuation rings as extensions

Tags: nt.number-theory, local-fields

Suppose $O$ is a complete discrete valuation ring with uniformizer $\pi$ and residue field $k=O/\pi O$ of charactersitc $p>0$.  If $\nu$ is the $\pi$-adic valuation on $K=Frac(O)$, suppose also that $\nu(p)>1$.

My question is that in this case, can we write $K$ as a (purely) ramified extension of some valuation field $K'$, whose valuation $\nu'$ satisfied $\nu'(p)=1$.  If so, is $O$ integral closure of the valuation ring $O'$ of $K'$ in $K$?

Hopefully that is well-posed, and thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: Yes. (It seems you mean to assume $K$ has characteristic 0.) Look up "Cohen structure theorem" in books on commutative algebra (e.g., Matsumura's "Commutative ring theory": Theorems 29.3 and 29.8(ii)).

Comment: Yes, I did mean that.  Thanks for the reference!